# c- format "%d" expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 3 has type int

Tags: c, image, int, compare, warnings

I'm new with C programming and I need to get images from two .dat files and compare if both of them are equal. The files first have the number of images, and then some images. I need to return 1 if all of the images are the same.

Pic of one of the .dat files:

[F1.dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKysJ.png)

The first 20 means 20 "groups" of images.
Then 3 4 would mean 3x4 matrix and the rest would be the matrix. The same with the other 19 matrices.

I need to go comparing the first matrix of the first file with the first one from the other file and so on.

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct irudia{
    int w,h;
    unsigned char im[16][16];
};

int berdinak (struct irudia *im1, struct irudia *im2){
int berdin = 1;
if ((im1->w != im2->w) || (im1->h != im2->h)){
    return 0;
}
for (int i = 0; i < im1 -> h; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < im1 -> w; j++){
        if (im1->im[i][j] != im2->im[i][j]){
            berdin = 0;
        }
    }
}
return berdin;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
int n1, n2;
int berdin = 1;
struct irudia i1, i2;
if (argc != 3){
    printf("Errorea parametroetan. Programa amaitu da.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
FILE *fitx1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
FILE *fitx2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
fscanf(fitx1, "%d", &n1);
fscanf(fitx2, "%d", &n2);
if (n1 != n2){
    return 0;
}
struct irudia *p1 = &i1;
struct irudia *p2 = &i2;
while (!feof(fitx1) && berdin == 1){
    fscanf (fitx1, "%d", &i1.h);
    fscanf (fitx1, "%d", &i1.w);
    fscanf (fitx2, "%d", &i2.h);
    fscanf (fitx2, "%d", &i2.w);
    for (int i = 0; i < i1.h; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < i1.w; j++){
            fscanf (fitx1, "%d", (unsigned char)(i1.im[i][j]));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < i2.h; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < i2.w; j++){
            fscanf (fitx2, "%d", (unsigned char)(i2.im[i][j]));
        }
    }
    berdin = berdinak (p1, p2);
}
    fclose (fitx1);
    fclose (fitx2);
    return berdin;
}
```

I don't need you to understand the code or anything like that. I need to know why I am getting a warning when I do

```
fscanf (fitx1, "%d", (unsigned char)(i1.im[i][j]));
```

Comment: The warning tells you very clearly. `%d` requires an `int *` for the variable arg but you gave it `i1.im[i][j]` which is not an `int *`. And don't do unneccessary casts.

Comment: Why would you expect to *not* get the error given in the title?  `fscanf()` requires you to pass a pointer; you are passing an `unsigned char`, automatically promoted to `int`.

Comment: i1.im[i][j] => i1.im[i] + j and stop cast !

Comment: Read a good C textbook, it will teach you how to use `scanf()` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`fscanf` reads the value into the provided address. Warnings are your friends. You are getting that particular warning because the compiler is telling you that it will interpret that value of `i1.im[i][j]` as an address and try to dereference it in order to put the scanned value inside. The likely result would be a segfault.

Instead try:

```
fscanf (fitx1, "%hhu", &(i1.im[i][j]));
```

Comment: Not quite, because `i1.im[i][j]` has type `unsigned char`.  The OP's cast was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

In these lines

```
fscanf (fitx1, "%d", (unsigned char)(i1.im[i][j]));
...
fscanf (fitx2, "%d", (unsigned char)(i2.im[i][j]));
```

you are supposed to pass the *address* of an `int` variable, but you are casting to the type it already is, which is not a address.

Your data *is* unsigned char but if you intend that to be a numeric value, I suggest you input to a temporary `int` variable, check its range, and then assign it to your array.

Also, please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: I did not get any warnings now. Instead of all that I put &x and then I assigned it.

Comment: I'll check the !feof link you sent. Thanks!

Comment: `feof` is a frequently misunderstood C function.